# How to deploy a play application(v.2.6) in Prod server?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I have written a set of RESTful APIs by using Play Framework 2.6.16 in Java.
I use dist command to make a zip file, and upzip it on my server which only installed JDK1.8.

$ unzip my-app-1.0.zip
$ my-app-1.0/bin/my-app -Dplay.http.secret.key=abcdefghijk

But I can't exit Play console after above command executed, Ctrl+D not working, Ctrl+C working but it also kill the app.

I don't know what to do next, does anybody have a solution?
Please give a help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply add a `&` character after any Linux command including the one you mentioned, to make it run in the background; after this, then you will get the process number (you could later terminate it based on that):

```
$ sbt clean compile run &
[1] 15791
```

**What to do next?** You asked what you need to do next, well, you could use Nginx as internet facing HTTP server, that redirects the incoming traffic into `localhost:9000` which is where your Play application is running.

Comment: Dear Seyed, you resolved my issue, thank you!!!! I really appreciate it! I can't believe it was so simply which blocked my for days, sorry for my poor linux skills, but your answer was so awesome to me.

Comment: @Totonoya No worries, glad I could help. All the best.